# JavaScript | Несколько popUp окон на странице

Tags: javascript, popup

Есть простенький скрипт, который позволяет открывать popup окно на странице. Подскажите, как нужно изменить этот скрипт, чтобы с его помощью можно было открывать несколько popup-окон на странице?

Подготовил пример:

```css
#Fpp-background {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 opacity: 0.8;
 overflow: auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.925);
}
#Fpp-window {
 display: none;
 background: #fff;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 200;
 height: auto;
 margin: 70px auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-y: auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 //Функция показа
 function show(state){
  document.getElementById('Fpp-window').style.display = state;
  document.getElementById('Fpp-background').style.display = state;
  }
</script> 
<div onclick="show('none')" id="Fpp-background"></div>

<!--01-->
<div id="Fpp-window">
  <p>Hide text</p>
  <button onclick="show('none')">Close</button>
</div>
<a href="#open" onclick="show('block')"><!--Открыть-->
  <p>Click open 01</p>
</a>

<!--02-->
<div id="Fpp-window">
  <p>Hide text 02</p>
  <button onclick="show('none')">Close</button>
</div>
<a href="#open" onclick="show('block')"><!--Открыть-->
  <p>Click open 02</p>
</a>
```

Здесь **Click open 01** работает, как надо. А **Click open 02** уже нет. Подозреваю, что задача очень простая для тех, кто знает javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что `id` это уникальный элемент на странице, а у вас 2 блока с одинаковым `id`, поэтому когда вы вызываете `getElementById('Fpp-window')` он находит первый и применяет действия к нему.

Чтобы прописать один стиль, разным блокам, в `css` используют классы.

Вот Ваш рабочий пример:

```css
#Fpp-background {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.8;
    overflow: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.925);
}
.Fpp-window {
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 200;
    height: auto;
    margin: 70px auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-y: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Функция показа
    function show(state, id){
        if(id!=null)
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = state;
         else{
            document.getElementById('Fpp-window').style.display = state;
            document.getElementById('Fpp-window-second').style.display = state;
         }
    document.getElementById('Fpp-background').style.display = state;
    }
</script>   
<div onclick="show('none')" id="Fpp-background"></div>

<!--01-->
<div id="Fpp-window" class="Fpp-window">
  <p>Hide text</p>
  <button onclick="show('none', 'Fpp-window')">Close</button>
</div>
<a href="#open" onclick="show('block', 'Fpp-window')"><!--Открыть-->
  <p>Click open 01</p>
</a>

<!--02-->
<div id="Fpp-window-second" class="Fpp-window">
  <p>Hide text 02</p>
  <button onclick="show('none', 'Fpp-window-second')">Close</button>
</div>
<a href="#open" onclick="show('block', 'Fpp-window-second')"><!--Открыть-->
  <p>Click open 02</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Komdosh, благодарю! Вы мне помогли, скрипт работает как надо.